# Notepad++ Don't skip to next instance after search and replace

Tags: notepad++, search, regex, find-and-replace

I am using the search and replace function in notepad++. Since it involves some regex, I would like to see the result after each single search and replace. However, if I click on Replace, the instance is replaced, and the editor automatically skips to the next instance, making it impossible for me to see the result without scrolling back. How can I disable this behaviour?

Answer (score 2):

#### I would like to disable the automatic skip to next match when using replace

This is not configurable as the developers chose not to provide this functionality.

You could either [make a feature request](https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/issues) or [download the source code](https://github.com/donho/notepad-plus-plus) and implement it yourself.